# how can i display text below listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an problem to displaying text below listview.when items are more in list the below text is not appear in my emulator. how can i solve this. i have use the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/bg1"
       android:shrinkColumns="*"
       android:stretchColumns="*" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/t7"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:text=""
           android:textColor="#000033"
           android:typeface="serif" />
       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/fromstation"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text=""
           android:textColor="#DC143C"
           android:layout_gravity="left"
           android:typeface="serif"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/to"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="To"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:typeface="serif"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tostation"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text=""
             android:textColor="#DC143C"
             android:layout_gravity="right"
           android:typeface="serif"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tname"
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:text="Train"
               android:layout_gravity="left"
               android:textColor="#9400D3"
               android:typeface="serif"
                >
           </TextView>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/arr"
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Arrival"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:textColor="#9400D3"
               android:typeface="serif" >
           </TextView>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/dep"
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="  Departure"
               android:textColor="#9400D3"

                 android:layout_gravity="right"     
               android:typeface="serif" >
           </TextView>
       </TableRow>


       <ListView
                  android:id="@id/android:list"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                  >

       </ListView>
       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/enq"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:text="*Marked services do not run on sunday."
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
           android:textColor="#800000"
           android:typeface="serif" />

        </LinearLayout>   

   </TableLayout>
```

can anyone tell me where i have done wrong.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, `android:layout_weight="1"` and change `layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` inside lsitview and the below layoutview

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enq"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*Marked services do not run on sunday."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

P.S. For make a space of listview lager than the below layout use Proportion of android:layout_weight to 1:3(Listview 1: the belowlayout 3)  or any Propotion you want

Answer (score -2):

Jusy give the listview height like

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```